# iphone built in gallery viewer

Tags: iphone, ios, gallery

In my application I have a list of  UIImages downloaded from web. I need to create a gallery where these images can be rotatable, zoomable and swap to view the next and previous. Is there a way to open images in iphone built in gallery viewer. or I will have to make it all through.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is known as UIImagePickerController.

Check this for more details :

```
http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/
```